# Modal JDialog disappear when clicking on parent Window

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

I'm trying to learn Java (not a programmer by profession).

I'm currently working on a calendar app with Postgres backend.

My app consists of a JFrame with two JPanels. One of those Panels is a CalendarView(MonthView, WeekView, or DayView), and the other a ButtonPanel.

The ButtonPanel has a button to add a new Event to the Calendar. This button opens a JDialog for entering Event details (startDate, endDate, title, etc).

The owner of the dialog is the JFrame. The dialog is modular.

The issues I have is that when the dialog is open, if I click on the parent window, the dialog disappears. If I then move the cursor outside the main application window and back in, the dialog reappears. I was under the impression that this should not happen with a modal component.

All feedback appreciated. I made a slimmed down SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class Calendar extends JFrame {

    public Calendar() {
        super("Calendar");
        initGUI();
    }

    public void initGUI() {
        JPanel calendarView = new JPanel();
        calendarView.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        calendarView.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), "Calendar view", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.CENTER));

        JPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED), "Button panel", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.CENTER));
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));

        this.getContentPane().add(calendarView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Calendar();
            }
        });
    }
}

mport java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {

    public ButtonPanel() {
        initGui();
    }

    private void initGui() {

        GridBagLayout gbag = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        this.setLayout(gbag);

        JButton button = new JButton("Open dialog");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                new MyDialog((JFrame) ButtonPanel.this.getTopLevelAncestor());
            }
        });

        gbag.setConstraints(button, gbc);
        this.add(button);
    }

}

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyDialog extends JDialog {

    public MyDialog(JFrame owner) {
        super(owner, "My dialog", true);
        initGUI(owner);
    }

    private void initGUI(JFrame owner){
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(createPanel(), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, createButtons(), createButtons()[0]);
        this.add(optionPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), "My dialog", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.CENTER));
        return panel;
    }

    private JButton[] createButtons() {
        JButton[] buttons = new JButton[1];
        JButton button = new JButton("Exit");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                MyDialog.this.dispose();
            }

        });
        buttons[0] = button;
        return buttons;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I made a slimmed down SSCCE:* -  A SSCCE should be fully contained in a single source file that we can copy/paste/compile/test. Your application is not important only code strictly relevant to the stated problem should be included. So all you need is a frame with a button that displays the dialog. The "calendarView" panel and Borders are irrelevant to the problem. The JOptionPane and buttons in your dialog are irrelevant to the problem. Having said all that, the code looked good to me, so I took the time to copy the files and test. The code worked fine for me.

Comment: The dialog was always on top of the frame and the frame could not be clicked. I use JDK11 on Windows 10. I suggest you include your platform and version so other using the same setup can test. *The dialog is modular.* - that should be "modal" not modular.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I use JDK 11 on Arch Linux with i3wm.